# Airflow Task is not failing for Snowflake Query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

I'm running a Snowflake procedure thru Airflow python operator task.
Airflow task is not getting failed when there is an runtime error in Snowflake Proc.

Below is the code snippet.

```
def load():
    try:
        dwh_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=Variable.get("SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID"), warehouse=Variable.get("SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE"), database=app_db, role=Variable.get("SNOWFLAKE_ROLE"), schema=app_stg_schema)
        con = dwh_hook.get_conn()
        cursor = con.cursor()

        # Execute the stored procedure
        call_sp_load_data_s3_to_snowflake = "call {0}.{1}.{2}('{3}','{4}','{5}')".format(db,schema, 'SP_LOAD_DATA_S3_TO_SNOWFLAKE', application_name, config_db,config_schema)
        cursor.execute(call_sp_load_data_s3_to_snowflake)
        con.commit()

        
        # Close cursor and connection
        cursor.close()
        con.close()
        move_files_within_bucket(file_names)
        print("file_names:", file_names)
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", str(e))
        raise e

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2023, 8, 22),
    'catchup':False,
    'email': ['abc@gmail.com'],
    'retries': 0,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    #'email_on_success': True,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
}




with DAG('project_s3_to_sf',
         default_args=default_args,
         ) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start',
        dag=dag
        )


    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="data_load_main",
        python_callable=data_load_filewise,
        #raise_airflow_exception=True,
        dag=dag

    )
    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end',
        dag=dag
        )


start>>t1>>end
```

It is processing with the next step with out failing. Can someone help me on this to get failed when there is a Snowflake Query failure.

**DAG LOG Step:**

```
[2023-10-27 11:47:26,797] {{cursor.py:609}} INFO - query: [call SP_LOAD_DATA_S3_TO_SNOWFLAKE(...] **(this step is failing in the Snowflake but the Airflow DAG not throwing any error)**
[2023-10-27 11:47:37,727] {{cursor.py:633}} INFO - query execution done
[2023-10-27 11:47:37,728] {{cursor.py:609}} INFO - query: [COMMIT]
[2023-10-27 11:47:37,792] {{cursor.py:633}} INFO - query execution done
[2023-10-27 11:47:37,852] {{cursor.py:633}} INFO - query execution done
[2023-10-27 11:47:37,853] {{arrow_result.pyx:0}} INFO - fetching data done
[2023-10-27 11:47:37,853] {{connection.py:482}} INFO - closed
[2023-10-27 11:47:37,882] {{connection.py:485}} INFO - No async queries seem to be running, deleting session
```

Comment: I recommend replicating this logic outside of Airflow & seeing if it fails outside Airflow

Comment: When you say the SP is failing, do you mean that the call of the SP itself is failing (because e.g. the SP doesn’t exist, or is not available to the user) or do you mean that code inside the SP is failing? If it’s the second case, how are you trapping this error and returning it from your SP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SnowflakeOperator which uses snowflake conn id, which you can set up in the same way.

1. You need to create_procedure.sql pass it in the operator

```
use database
use schema
call. myproc()
```

2. Change the airflow code to this , refer from here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/operators/snowflake.html

```
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook


export AIRFLOW_CONN_SNOWFLAKE_DEFAULT='{
    "conn_type": "snowflake",
    "login": "user",
    "password": "password",
    "schema": "db-schema",
    "extra": {
        "account": "account",
        "database": "database",
        "region": "us-east",
        "warehouse": "snow-warehouse"
    }
}'




default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2023, 8, 22),
    'catchup':False,
    'email': ['abc@gmail.com'],
    'retries': 0,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    #'email_on_success': True,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
}
with DAG('project_s3_to_sf', default_args=default_args,) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start', dag=dag)


    t1 = SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id="snowflake_op_sql_str", 
        sql="path/create_procedure.sql")


    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end',
        dag=dag
        )


start>>t1>>end
```